How to navigate in SwiftUI while also executing logic and creating a new Object?
I have a EditTapasView which is there to edit any Tapas created by the user. To create one, they can press a "New Tapas" button, sending them to exactly this EditTapasView with a newly created Tapas.
Until now it all worked with using a sheet.
Button(action: {
    newTapas = addTapas()
    /// Delay the toggle of the Sheet by .1 second.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
         shouldPresentSheet.toggle()
    }
}, label: {
    Text("New Tapas")
        .font(.system(size: 17))
        .padding(.trailing)
        .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
})
   .sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentSheet) {
       print("Sheet dismissed!")
    } content: {
       EditTapasView(tapas: newTapas)
    }

But now I have added a new NavigationLink inside of the EditTapasView to make some edits, and this part is not working in a sheet.
When I just use a NavigationLink and giving it the addTapas() function, it constantly creates new Tapas without any click.
NavigationLink(destination: EditTapasView(tapas: addTapas())) {
    Text("New Tapas")
        .font(.system(size: 17))
        .padding(.trailing)
        .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
}

Then I researched how to navigate progamatically, but I couldn't make it work.
NavigationStack (path: $path) {
    Button(action: {
        newTapas = addTapas()
        path = EditTapasView(tapas: newTapas)
    }, label: {
        Text("New Tapas")
            .font(.system(size: 17))
            .padding(.trailing)
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
    })
}

So is there any way to solve my problem? Either to simply use NavigationLink (or similar) in the Action part of a button? Or to have some logic execute once a NavigationLink is pressed?
The desired outcome is to have a programatic Navigation which works from a simple button press.

First, using asyncAfter is a code smell. You would have been better having two different sheet closures, one that created your new object, but you have gotten rid of that now.  Can you [edit] your question to show your EditTapasView? It is probably easier to modify that so that it accepts an optional tapas and it is responsible for creating the new object on dismiss. This will also make it possible for the user to cancel without having to delete the new tapas

Watch “Meet asymc/await”

I used asyncAfter as sometimes the sheet was so quick it was generated before the NewTapas, that led to strange behaviour. Actually this worked. I can imagine it is a bit hacky, but I also used asyncAfter in my Intro for the App, for letting Text appear after certain times. Is there a better way for this?
I tried to make it an optional Tapas in there, but I didn't want to change the whole code to handle optionals. I also tried @State var tapas: Tapas ?? addTapas(). So to create a new one only if none was given, but this didn't work. Is there a default for var declaration?

There's probably a few different ways a simple way would be to use navigationDestination if it's not too buggy. The NavigationStacks and NavigationSplitViews aren't really ready for production yet.
@State private var newTapa: Tapa?

var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Add Tapas") {
                newTapa = Tapa()
            }
            .navigationDestination(item: newTapa) { tapa in
                TapaEditView(tapa: tapa)
            }
        }
}

//UPDATE:
The following code compiles just fine. In the code above I forgot to make newTapa a binding. Other than that you may have a compile issue elsewhere.
import SwiftUI


struct Tapa: Hashable {
    var name = "Tapa Name"
}

struct TapaEditView: View {
    let tapa: Tapa

    var body: some View {
        Text(tapa.name)
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @State private var newTapa: Tapa?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Add Tapas") {
                newTapa = Tapa()
            }
            .navigationDestination(item: $newTapa) { tapa in
                TapaEditView(tapa: tapa)
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried this, but Swift won't let me even do your State var declaration like this. Tapas? and also Tapas()? Doesn't work and gives these respective errors: "Expected member name or constructor call after type name" and "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of Tapas".

NavigationPath is correct for programatic navigation, just need to change it to this:
NavigationStack (path: $path) {
    Button(action: {
        let newTapas = newTapas()
        path.append(newTapas)  // this calls navigationDestination
    }, label: {
        Text("New Tapas")
            .font(.system(size: 17))
            .padding(.trailing)
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
    })
    .navigationDestination(for: Tapas.self) { newTapas in
        EditTapasView(tapas: newTapas)
    }
}

And your Tapas model type needs to be a class in this case.
Note in your first attempt that uses DispatchQueue, you can't use asyncAfter in SwiftUI because the Views are just structs, i.e. values that have no lifetime. After the UI has been described the Views are gone.

I tried this approach, but in the navigationDestination it says "Cannot find newTapas in scope'. I deleted the @State var new Tapas and took your approach of making it a constant. When I had it as a State var the line "path = [newTapas] gave an error (Cannot assign Type of Tapas to type NavigationPath.

Sorry fixed that and here is the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationpath

In your version the .navgitationDestination could not find the new Tapas as it is declared as a let inside of the Button. The other solution with the Binding worked, even though I hoped your more simple version would also work out. Or did I make an error?

Sorry fixed that and here is the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(for:destination:)
